# Possible images of line under linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Consider this line:
$\overrightarrow a = \overrightarrow p +t(\overrightarrow v)$
Where $\overrightarrow p$ is any vector in $\mathbb R^n$, and $\overrightarrow v$ is any nonzero vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

Given linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, what are the possible images of the line under the map T? Through intuition I understand that it is either a line or a single point, but do not know where to start in showing that mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

By linearity of $T$,
$$T(p+tv) = T(p) + tT(v),$$
for any real number $t$.
This looks like the equation for a line (just look back at your original expression $p+tv$; we have replaced $p$ with $T(p)$, and $v$ with $T(v)$).
Indeed, it is a line as long as $T(v) \ne 0$; otherwise, it is just the point $T(p)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is a linear transformation, we have:
$$T(\vec a)=T(\vec p+t\vec v)=T(\vec p)+tT(\vec v)$$
Notice that $T(\vec p)$ and $T(\vec v)$ are vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, so $T(\vec a)$ is a line or a point. If $T(\vec v)$ is nonzero, then $T(\vec a)$ is a line, similar to $\vec a$. If $T(\vec v)$ is zero, then $T(\vec a)=T(\vec p)~~~\forall t\in\Bbb R$, so $T(\vec a)$ is a single point in $\Bbb R^n$ in this case.

Note that if $T$ is injective, then $\ker(T)=\{\vec 0\}$ and thus $T(\vec v)=\vec 0\iff \vec v=\vec 0$. Hence, if $\vec v\neq\vec 0$ by assumption, then $T(\vec v)\neq\vec 0$, and thus $T(\vec a)$ is a line.

Answer (score 1):

Let your original line be $L_1=\{\vec {p}+t\vec{v}:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Then you're interested in the set of vectors: $$L_2=\{T(\vec x):\vec x\in L_1\}=\{T(\vec {p}+t\vec {v}):t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{T(\vec {p})+tT(\vec {v}):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$$

$T(\vec p)$ is just a constant vector. The nature of $L_2$ will depend on $T(\vec v)$. If $T(\vec v)$ is non-zero, then you have a line. Else you have a point.